# Algorithm for taking the shortest path between two XY coordinates

Tags: javascript, coordinates, phaser

I am making a simple game in Phaser (but the library doesn't really matter).

I have an enemy that is moving towards the player on a 2 dimensional grid. I have written some code that makes the enemy move towards the player:

```
moveEnemy(enemy){
    var playerX = getPlayerX(); // a number
    var playerY = getPlayerY(); // a number 

    // if the enemy X or Y coordinate is smaller or larger than the players,
    // increase or decrease the enemy X or Y to move closer. 
    var newX = enemy.x > playerX ? enemy.x - 0.2 : enemy.x + 0.2;
    var newY = enemy.y > playerY ? enemy.y - 0.2 : enemy.y + 0.2;
    enemy.setPosition(newX, newY);
}
```

I expected this code to move the enemy towards the player in the shortest route possible. However, I get the following situation:

[image]

The green route is what I expected the enemy to take. In reality, the enemy follows the red line: first it goes down in a 45 degree angle, before going towards the player in a straight horizontal line. I'm at a loss how to make my enemies move along the green line.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of vectors. The library actually does matter here, because Phaser already [has a vector class](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.54.0/Phaser.Math.Vector2) which is probably going to make this a lot easier.But I never used Phaser before, so I will leave the answer to this question to someone more familiar with the library.

Comment: Thanks Philipp, this helps me out a bit already. I'm a backend developer with zero experience in game development, so I got my homework cut out for me.

Comment: Thanks @Philipp, it took some reading  but I figured it out. It's literally 2 lines of code in the Phaser library!

Comment: When you figured it out, then please post an answer to your own question so others can benefit from your knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code makes him move vertical and horizontal if needed.

He moves the same speed both vertical and horizontal, that's why you only get a 45 degree angle.

He moves like this until there is no need to move vertical, and he only moves horizontal the last bit.

To solve this you need first to calculate `deltaX = enemy.x - playerX` and `deltaY` between the two points, and move the portion of distance in each direction, and he will move directly from A to B.

You'll need to know the distance to set constant speed. Find it with `theDistance = Math.sqrt(dX*dX+dY*dY)` with the squareroot-method.

I suggest unifying the direction by dividing `deltaX/theDistance` over the distance to get your direction, then you can just multiply this with the speed you want on the enemy.